# having troubles in Color Game Logic

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm new to vb.net programming. I created a color game where there are 3 buttons with color green, yellow, and red on it and a maximum of 3 clicks before it restarts the loop again. Once the user press a specific combination of colors, the program will display whether they won a jackpot prize, consolation prize, or nothing. If the same color was pressed 3 times then it will display a jackpot prize, if the same color was pressed 2 times and the 3rd color is different then it will display a consolation prize, then lastly if all colors was pressed once then it will display "sorry try again". I'm having problem with the logic part of the game where if I press specifically green, yellow and red as first combination of colors then it will display "sorry try again", then when I press green or yellow 3 times as the second combination of colors it will display the consolation prize instead of the jackpot prize, but if I try red 3 times it will do nothing for the rest of the loop unless I restart the game again but if I try other combinations first it works perfectly fine just the "green, yellow, red" combination will the game will bug out.

here's the logic of the game:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    i = i + 1
    g = g + 1
    MessageBox.Show("g:" & g)
    MessageBox.Show("i:" & i)
    If g = 2 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won the consolation prize")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.You_win_sound_effect_5, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        conwon()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf g = 1 And y = 1 And r = 1 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("Better luck Next time")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Fail___sound_effect_, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        sorry()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf y = 1 And g = 1 And r = 1 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("Better luck Next time")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Fail___sound_effect_, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        sorry()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf r = 1 And y = 1 And g = 1 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("Better luck Next time")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Fail___sound_effect_, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        sorry()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf g = 2 And y = 1 Or r = 1 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won a consolation prize")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.You_win_sound_effect_5, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        conwon()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf y = 2 And g = 1 Or r = 1 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won a consolation prize")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.You_win_sound_effect_5, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        conwon()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf r = 2 And g = 1 Or y = 1 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won a consolation prize")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.You_win_sound_effect_5, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        conwon()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf g = 3 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won the Jackpot prize")
        Form3.PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.jackpot
        Form3.Show()
        jacwon()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf y = 3 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won the Jackpot prize")
        Form3.PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.jackpot
        Form3.Show()
        jacwon()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf r = 3 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won the Jackpot prize")
        Form3.PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.jackpot
        Form3.Show()
        jacwon()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    i = i + 1
    y = y + 1
    MessageBox.Show("y:" & y)
    MessageBox.Show("i:" & i)
    If y = 2 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won the consolation prize")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.You_win_sound_effect_5, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        conwon()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf y = 1 And g = 1 And r = 1 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("Better luck Next time)
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Fail___sound_effect_, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        sorry()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf g = 1 And y = 1 And r = 1 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("Better luck Next time")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Fail___sound_effect_, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        sorry()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf r = 1 And y = 1 And g = 1 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("Better luck Next time")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Fail___sound_effect_, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        sorry()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf g = 2 And y = 1 Or r = 1 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won a consolation prize")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.You_win_sound_effect_5, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        conwon()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf y = 2 And g = 1 Or r = 1 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won a consolation prize")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.You_win_sound_effect_5, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        conwon()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf r = 2 And g = 1 Or y = 1 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won a consolation prize")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.You_win_sound_effect_5, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        conwon()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf y = 3 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won the Jackpot prize")
        Form3.PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.jackpot
        Form3.Show()
        jacwon()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf g = 3 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won the Jackpot prize")
        Form3.PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.jackpot
        Form3.Show()
        jacwon()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf r = 3 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won the Jackpot prize")
        Form3.PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.jackpot
        Form3.Show()
        jacwon()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    i = i + 1
    r = r + 1
    MessageBox.Show("r:" & r)
    MessageBox.Show("i:" & i)
    If r = 2 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won the consolation prize")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.You_win_sound_effect_5, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        conwon()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf r = 1 And g = 1 And y = 1 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("Better luck Next time")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Fail___sound_effect_, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        sorry()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf y = 1 And g = 1 And r = 1 And i = 3 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Better luck Next time")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Fail___sound_effect_, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        sorry()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf g = 1 And y = 1 And r = 1 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("Better luck Next time")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Fail___sound_effect_, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        sorry()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf g = 2 And y = 1 Or r = 1 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won a consolation prize")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.You_win_sound_effect_5, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        conwon()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf y = 2 And g = 1 Or r = 1 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won a consolation prize")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.You_win_sound_effect_5, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        conwon()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf r = 2 And g = 1 Or y = 1 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won a consolation prize")
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.You_win_sound_effect_5, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        conwon()
        Form2.Show()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf r = 3 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won the Jackpot prize")
        Form3.PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.jackpot
        Form3.Show()
        jacwon()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf g = 3 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won the Jackpot prize")
        Form3.PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.jackpot
        Form3.Show()
        jacwon()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0
    ElseIf y = 3 And i = 3 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You won the Jackpot prize")
        Form3.PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.jackpot
        Form3.Show()
        jacwon()
        i = 0
        g = 0
        r = 0
        y = 0

    End If
End Sub
```

any help would be Appreciated.

Comment: This is a debugging question - a *great* chance for you to learn how to debug code.  VS comes with a great debugger - set a breakpoint and step thru the code line by line.  Watch what happens, see the value of variables using the mouse.  You will learn a lot about how code actually works/runs which will improve your programming skills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in a comment, this is a debugging question, but the program is overly complex for what it needs to do. So it's also a design problem. When you are writing code, if you ever find yourself write the same thing twice, or close-to-the-same-thing twice, then you should encapsulate the logic in a method. There was a *lot* of this in your program. I simplified it, and now you will find that it will work properly. It should be easier to understand and to debug, making it less of a debugging *project*.

```
Private g As Integer = 0, y As Integer = 0, r As Integer = 0
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    g += 1 : processResult()
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    y += 1 : processResult()
End Sub
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    r += 1 : processResult()
End Sub
Private Sub processResult()
    Select Case {g, y, r}.Max() * {g, y, r}.Sum()
        Case 3 ' 3 different colors
            loser() : clearCounters()
        Case 6 ' 2 and 1
            consolation() : clearCounters()
        Case 9 ' all same color
            jackpot() : clearCounters()
    End Select ' cases 0, 1, 2, 4 ignored as game is not complete
End Sub
Private Sub loser()
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Fail___sound_effect_, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    sorry() : Form2.Show()
End Sub
Private Sub consolation()
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.You_win_sound_effect_5, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    conwon() : Form2.Show()
End Sub
Private Sub jackpot()
    Form3.PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.jackpot
    Form3.Show()
    jacwon()
End Sub
Private Sub clearCounters()
    g = 0 : y = 0 : r = 0
End Sub
```

*In an effort to fit on one screen for the answer, multiple lines are sometimes concatenated with `:`*

You don't need a counter, since the state is in the sum of `g`, `y`, and `r`. When the sum is 3, the game is over. Also, there are three distinct states when the sum is three. The max value is either 3, 2, or 1 representing all one color, two colors, and three colors, respectively. The combination of these two calculations cover all your cases the following way:

```
         |  game over  |  game active
---------|-------------|---------------
colorA   |  3   2   1  |  2   1   1   0
colorB   |  0   1   1  |  0   1   0   0
colorC   |  0   0   1  |  0   0   0   0
---------|-------------|---------------
max*sum  |  9   6   3  |  4   2   1   0
outcome  |  j   c   l  |  n   n   n   n
```

So using a `Switch` statement on the state of the game can tell you exactly how to proceed, whether the game is over and you need to pick a winner, or the game is still active and you need to do nothing.

Here are all the possible states

[image]

With 10 states when the game is over. So the chance of losing is 1/10, consolation is 6/10, and jackpot is 3/10. I sure hope you aren't the house.

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you for explaining it thoroughly.